# Tensorflow Keras Neural Network Model Clear GPU Memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a neural network with keras.
I am using `Windows 10` and installed `tensorflow` on my GPU `NVIDA GeForce 1060` therefore I am using CUDA : `10.0` and tensorflow `2.3.0`.

Basically this works if I run it one time alone but I now want to find the best configuration for this network therefore I am trying to build the model every time and then find the best. I am planning on doing that in an for loop.
But my model depends on exactly that parameters data, the model look like:

```
model_heightmap = Sequential(
        [
            # Input(shape=(140, 150)),
            # Reshape(target_shape=(140 * 150,), input_shape=(140, 150)),
            Flatten(input_shape=(140, 150)),
            Dense(8000, activation='relu'),
            Dense(5000, activation='relu'),
            Dense(3000, activation='relu'),
            Dense(500, activation='relu'),
            Dense(200, activation='relu'),
            Dense(5, activation='softmax'),
            Dense(df_max_cat + 1, activation='softmax')
        ]
    )
```

So here is the `df_max_cat` the changing factor.
But when the for loop comes to its second iteration it gets the following error:
`2020-10-03 13:45:29.899409: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:775] failed to allocate 818.20M (857944832 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory` 
I know that this mistakes happens because I run out of memory and this happens because I create the model every time new.
I don't need the old models so how am I able to clear up the old GPU Memory Space for the next run ???
I have already tried:

```
del model_heightmap  # for avoid any trace on aigen
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()  # removing session, it will instance another
```

Does anybody has any ideas how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'd also have thought `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` is the way to go, but I'm new to TF. Can you reproduce this issue reliably, possibly with a MWE?

Comment: I could try once you explain me what MWE stand for ? ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Minimal Working Example :)